# How to change the circuit to adapt to a new power triangle

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

I've been given a single-phase load represented by the power triangle in Fig.1, powered by 200[V] (rms) at an angular frequency of \$w=400\frac{[rad]}{[s]}\$. I would like to rephase the load such that the new power triangle is represented in Fig.2.

How can I find the capacitance of the capacitor in parallel with the load?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Homework.

If the existing 7kVAr happens to be already capacitive, no extra capacitor will do the job.

If your load is inductive, calculate a capacitor which takes alone 4kVAr capacitive reactive power from the same operating voltage and connect it in parallel with the load.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to circuits. What happens if I connect a capacitor in series with the load?

Comment: We wouldn't (usually) connect a capacitor in series with a load because it would reduce the voltage to the load.

Comment: @Transistor recheck. Think a series capacitor which happens to compensate exactly the reactive part of the total load impedance. The current grows. How it could grow without having more voltage over the original load?